# Add Zooming to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been doing the tutorials in the Big Nerd Ranch Iphone development book and ran into an issue I can't solve or find an answer for.

The App (Hypnosister) basically just draws a bunch of concentric circles and places some text on the screen using the DrawRect method. I got that to work and I was able to add scrolling ot the view but can't add the ability zoom. I've checked my code 100 times and can't figure it out. I think they used an earlier version of the OS and I am using 4.2. Did something change? Can you find the issue?

Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface HypnosisterAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,
UIScrollViewDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
    HypnosisView *view;
}
```

and this goes in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions part:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and method gets called after that method closes:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return view;
}
```

HypnosisView is a UIView class that does the drawing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the examples for the book from the Big Nerd Ranch website and it works fine on the simulator under 1OS 4.3. Did you add these lines of code to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Enable zooming
[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];
[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:5];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

This is only possible problem I can think of based on the code you've shown.

Comment: Thanks Mark! That was it. Apparently this is missing from the Kindle version of the book I have.